# bandwidth usage suddenly increased in wordpress site after wordpress 3.5 update

Tags: wordpress, bandwidth

I am facing bandwidth issue, for last (2012) whole year bandwidth usage of my wordpress site was 11.66 GB, after updating wordpress to version 3.5 in early january 2013, bandwidth usage for my site for jan-2013 is 38.76 GB.

do anyone have any idea for this issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you FTP to your site and check all your sub directories... I have had this before, and it was a result of the FTP being hacked and someone hosting p0rn images on my hosted domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've also hit a massive spike in outgoing bandwidth since the update.  When I'm editing a post and uploading media, it now shows the nice grid of available pictures, but it seems to be downloading the entire picture each time rather than a thumbnail.